# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError con CLASSPATH explícito

Tags: java, maven

Tengo un proyecto mínimo que usa la librería `spark-sql`.

Mi `pom.xml` es el siguiente:

```
<project>
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>malaga.indizen.com</groupId>
  <artifactId>calles</artifactId>
  <version>1.0</version>

  <properties>
    <maven.compiler.target>8</maven.compiler.target>
    <maven.compiler.source>8</maven.compiler.source>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <maven.test.skip>true</maven.test.skip>     
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency> <!-- Spark dependency -->
      <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
      <artifactId>spark-sql_2.12</artifactId>
      <version>2.4.5</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <archive>
            <manifest>
              <mainClass>Calles</mainClass>
            </manifest>
          </archive>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>copy-dependencies</id>
            <phase>prepare-package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/libs</outputDirectory>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

Al ejecutar `mvn package`, después de *sus cositas*, me genera lo siguiente:

> root
>   +-target
>   |  +-calles-1.0.jar
>   |  +libs
>         +-spark-sql_2.12-2.4.5.jar
>   ...

Una vez compilado, me sitúo en el directorio `target`, e intento ejecutar:

> >cd target
>   >CLASSPATH='/calles/target/libs' java -jar calles-1.0.jar

Pero parece que **no le gusta**:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/spark/sql/SparkSession at Calles.main(Calles.java:10)
>   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
>     at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
>     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
>     at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:352)
>     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
>     ... 1 more

También he intentado:

- Indicando como `CLASSPATH` la ruta relativa

  ```
  >cd target
  >CLASSPATH='libs' java -jar calles-1.0.jar
  ```
- Cambiando el `scope` de la dependencia en en `pom.xml`. En este caso, me ha mostrado distintos errores de compilación, así que lo he dejado como indico, `<scope>compile</scope>`.
- Colocando en `CLASSPATH` la lista de **todos** los `.jar`, separados por `:` (estoy en Linux):

  ```
  CLASSPATH=`find /root/calles/target/libs | paste -sd ':'` java -jar calles-1.0.jar
  ```

Y siempre he obtenido el mismo resultado.

**No** estoy usando ningún IDE; estoy dentro de un docker basado en Ubuntu 20.04 LTS, donde solo tengo un editor de texto.

- ¿ Que estoy haciendo mal ?
- ¿ Cómo lo soluciono ?

Comment: Puede que [este articuo de SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45412593/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-org-apache-spark-sql-sparksession) te ayude

Comment: En el maven-jar-plugin te está faltando indicar que incluya el class path e indicar cuál es la clase principal (la que tiene el main). Ver el primer caso de este tutorial: https://www.baeldung.com/executable-jar-with-maven. Luego no tenes que modificar la variable de CLASSPATH en OS.

Comment: El main class en el tag del plugin debe ser full qualified: `com.indizen.malaga.bla.Calles`

Comment: @Juan, el `<mainClass>Calles</mainClass>` es correcto. Lo primero que tengo en mi `main( )` es un `println( ... )` y eso **si** lo imprime. El problema no va por ahí, está en la carga de los `.jar` con las dependencias.

Comment: Fijate el link que te mandé. Ahi hay un par de tags para declarar el class path. Y las veces que yo lo he hecho he tenido que poner el main class con el package completo. En el articulo, el caso tuyo es el primer ejemplo que da.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El siguiente ejemplo lo hice siguiendo las lineas que planteaste: sin ide, solo con maven y un editor de texto.
Use un ubunto 18.04 casi pelado, incluso para hacer el ejemplo tuve que instalar maven.

El ejemplo lo hice usando `Gson` como librería externa en lugar de `spark`.

En la pregunta no dice nada al respecto, pero use la estructura standard de directorios para un proyecto con maven.

Cuando terminé el ejemplo pude ejecutar el `jar` desde la carpeta `target` invocando `java -jar calles-1-0.jar`.

En el directorio `target` tenía tanto el `jar` como el directorio `lib` con el `jar` de `Gson`.

No fue necesario manipular ni el classpath en la linea de comando (`-cp`) ni modificar la variable de entorno.

Tomé el mismo `pom` que estabas usando y aparte de reemplazar las dependencias, hice los siguientes cambios en el `maven-jar-plugin` en la sección de `manifest`:

1) Agregar el tag `<addClasspath>true</addClasspath>`
2) Agregar el tag `<classpathPrefix>libs/</classpathPrefix>`
3) Colocar el nombre completo de la clase principal: `<mainClass>com.indizen.malaga.Calles</mainClass>`

**El Pom**

```
<project>
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>malaga.indizen.com</groupId>
  <artifactId>calles</artifactId>
  <version>1.0</version>

  <properties>
    <maven.compiler.target>8</maven.compiler.target>
    <maven.compiler.source>8</maven.compiler.source>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <maven.test.skip>true</maven.test.skip>     
  </properties>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
          <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.code.gson/gson -->
          <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
          <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
          <version>2.8.5</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <archive>
            <manifest>
                <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                <classpathPrefix>libs/</classpathPrefix> 
                <mainClass>com.indizen.malaga.Calles</mainClass>
            </manifest>
          </archive>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>copy-dependencies</id>
            <phase>prepare-package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/libs</outputDirectory>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

**La Clase Principal**

```
package com.indizen.malaga;

import com.google.gson.Gson;


public class Calles {
    public static void main(String [] args) {
        Calles calles = new Calles();

        calles.run(args);
    }

    public void run(String [] args) {
        UnaClaseSimple unaClaseSimple = new UnaClaseSimple();
        unaClaseSimple.setAtributo1("Hola");
        unaClaseSimple.setAtributo2("Todos");

        String json = new Gson().toJson(unaClaseSimple);
        System.out.println(json);

    }
}
```

**Una auxiliar para que el programa haga algo usando la libreria**

```
package com.indizen.malaga;

public class UnaClaseSimple {
    private String atributo1;
    private String atributo2;

    public String getAtributo1() {
        return this.atributo1;
    }

    public String getAtributo2() {
        return this.atributo2;
    }

    public void setAtributo1(final String s) {
        this.atributo1 = s;
    }

    public void setAtributo2(final String s) {
        this.atributo2 = s;
    }
}
```

**Resultado de la ejecución:**

```
[INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.4:install (default-install) @ calles ---
[INFO] Installing /home/jb007/Workspaces/java/ExecJar/target/calles-1.0.jar to /home/jb007/.m2/repository/malaga/indizen/com/calles/1.0/calles-1.0.jar
[INFO] Installing /home/jb007/Workspaces/java/ExecJar/pom.xml to /home/jb007/.m2/repository/malaga/indizen/com/calles/1.0/calles-1.0.pom
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  2.487 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2020-04-28T22:23:56-03:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
jb007@ubuntu:~/Workspaces/java/ExecJar$ cd target
jb007@ubuntu:~/Workspaces/java/ExecJar/target$ java -jar calles-1.0.jar
{"atributo1":"Hola","atributo2":"Todos"}
```

Answer (score 0):

creo que al hacer directamente mvn package, no has descargado en local, la libreria de spark, deberias hacer mvn install, antes de ejecutar: mvn package, para que pueda encontrar el jar de spark en tu máquina e incluirlo al empaquetarlo. Por esa razón no la encuentra.

Comment: En la pregunta indico la jerarquía de directorios que me resulta de `mvn package`, y, dentro de `libs`, **si está** `spark-sql_2.12-2.4.5.jar`

Comment: ¿Puedes subir el proyecto, para que veamos el error y te comentamos?