# ¿ Cómo funciona CLASSPATH?

Tags: java

A raiz de esta pregunta

[java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError con CLASSPATH explícito](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/350293/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-con-classpath-expl%c3%adcito)

Me ha surgido una duda. [La documentación de Oracle sobre `CLASSPATH`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html) nos indica:

> The class path tells JDK tools and applications where to find third-party and user-defined classes -- that is, classes that are not Java extensions or part of the Java platform. The class path needs to find any classes you've compiled with the javac compiler -- its default is the current directory to conveniently enable those classes to be found
>   ...
>   Class paths to the .jar, .zip or .class files. Each classpath should end with a filename or directory depending on what you are setting the class path to:
>
> - For a .jar or .zip file that contains .class files, the class path ends with the name of the .zip or .jar file.
> - For .class files in an unnamed package, the class path ends with the directory that contains the .class files.
> - For .class files in a named package, the class path ends with the directory that contains the "root" package (the first package in the full package name).
>     
>     Multiple path entries are separated by semi-colons.

Sin embargo, por mi experiencia, he llegado a la conclusión de que **todos** los tutoriales de Internet y la propia documentación **están mal**.

#### El caso concreto.

Pongamos un archivo de código mínimo, que use alguna librería externa:

```
import com.google.gson.Gson;

public class MCVE {
  public static void main( String [] args ) {
    System.out.println( " ***** Iniciando la prueba *****" );

    MCVE mcve = new MCVE( );
    String json = new Gson( ).toJson( mcve );
    System.out.println( json );

    System.out.println( " ***** Prueba terminada *****" );
  }
}
```

Igualmente, un `pom.xml` mínimo, pero **que nos copie las dependencias** a un directorio (en este caso, `target/libs`):

```
<project>
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>es.stackoverflow.com</groupId>
  <artifactId>MCVE</artifactId>
  <version>1.0</version>

  <properties>
    <maven.compiler.target>8</maven.compiler.target>
    <maven.compiler.source>8</maven.compiler.source>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <maven.test.skip>true</maven.test.skip>     
  </properties>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
          <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.code.gson/gson -->
          <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
          <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
          <version>2.8.5</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <archive>
            <manifest>
                <mainClass>MCVE</mainClass>
            </manifest>
          </archive>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>copy-dependencies</id>
            <phase>prepare-package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/libs</outputDirectory>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

Todo ello colocado en una jerarquía de directorios mas o menos estándar:

> /mcve
>   +-pom.xml
>   +-src
>      +-main
>         +-java
>            +-MCVE.java

Lo compilamos:

```
>mvn package
```

Tras lo cual, nuestra jerarquía de directorios contiene:

> /mcve
>   +-pom.xml
>   +-src/
>   |   +-main/
>   |      +-java/
>   |         +-MCVE.java
>   +-target/
>      +-MCVE-1.0.jar
>         +-libs/
>            +-gson-2.8.5.jar

Además, miramos dentro del `.jar`, el archivo `MANIFEST.MF`:

> Manifest-Version: 1.0
>   Archiver-Version: Plexus Archiver
>   Built-By: root
>   Created-By: Apache Maven 3.6.3
>   Build-Jdk: 1.8.0_252-ea
>   Main-Class: MCVE

Ahora, lo ejecutamos:

```
>cd target
>CLASSPATH='libs/' java -jar MCVE-1.0.jar
```

Pero parece que **no le gusta**:

> >java -jar MCVE-1.0.jar
>    ***** Iniciando la prueba *****
>   Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/gson/Gson
>    at MCVE.main(MCVE.java:9)
>   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.gson.Gson
>    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
>    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
>    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:352)
>    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
>    ... 1 more

**Seguimos probando** todas las posibles formas de indicar el `CLASSPATH`:

```
>CLASSPATH='libs' java -jar MCVE-1.0.jar
>CLASSPATH='/root/mcve/target/libs/' java -jar MCVE-1.0.jar
>CLASSPATH='/root/mcve/target/libs' java -jar MCVE-1.0.jar
>export CLASSPATH='/root/mcve/target/libs/'; java -jar MCVE-1.0.jar
>CLASSPATH='libs/gson-2.8.5.jar' java -jar MCVE-1.0.jar
>CLASSPATH='/root/mcve/target/libs/gson-2.8.5.jar' java -jar MCVE-1.0.jar
...
>java -cp 'libs/' -jar MCVE-1.0.jar
>java -cp 'libs/' -jar MCVE-1.0.jar
>java -cp '/root/mcve/target/libs/gson-2.8.5.jar' -jar MCVE-1.0.jar
...
```

En todos los casos obtengo la misma excepción.

#### ¿ En que fuente autorizada se explica y detalla un comportamiento de java y CLASSPATH acorde a los resultados observados ?

Comment: Versión en inglés de esta pregunta: [Run a JAR file from the command line and specify classpath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18413014/run-a-jar-file-from-the-command-line-and-specify-classpath)

Comment: Puedes añadir a tu pom.xml despues de donde tienes `<mainClass>MCVE</mainClass>` lo siguiente:                             `<classpathPrefix>libs/</classpathPrefix><addClasspath>true</addClasspath>`.Con esto consigues que te quede en e l MANIFEST.MF lo siguiente: `Class-Path: libs/gson-2.8.5.jar` y de esa manera puedes ejecutarlo normalmente con java -jar como en tu primer intento.

Comment: @ordago-QUÉDATEENCASA Eso es lo que me han respondido en mi *otra* pregunta ... pero me quedaba la duda **del porqué**. Ahora si está claro :-)

Comment: Wops, no leí la otra pregunta, en cualquier caso me alegro de que hayas dado con la respuesta

Answer (score 8, accepted):

El problema es el uso del comando `java` con parámetros incompatibles: Al estar ejecutando un jar, has puesto `-jar`, pero si vemos la documentación del comando para ese parámetro nos encontramos lo siguiente:

> -jar
>
> Executes a program encapsulated in a JAR file. The first argument is the name of a JAR file instead of a startup class name. For this
>   option to work, the manifest of the JAR file must contain a line in
>   the form Main-Class: classname. Here, classname identifies the class
>   with the public static void main(String[] args) method that serves as
>   your application's starting point.
>
> When you use this option, **the JAR file is the source of all user classes, and other user class path settings are ignored**.

(Las negritas son mías)

Si quieres ejecutar un jar con dependencias, tienes dos opciones:

- Añadir las dependencias en el classpath en el fichero MANIFEST.MF:

  ```
  Class-Path: jar1-name jar2-name directory-name/jar3-name
  ```
- Añadir el jar con la clase Main al classpath, usando `-cp` en lugar de `-jar`. Esto hace que el fichero Manifest se ignore, con lo que tendrás que declarar explícitamente la clase que tiene el método `main`:

  ```
  java -cp MyJar.jar:lib/* com.somepackage.subpackage.Main
  ```

Comment: También hay forma de incluir las dependencias dentro del jar ejecutable (hacer un "Uber jar"). Con maven están estos plugins:  "Apache Maven Assembly Plugin" y "Apache Maven Shade Plugin" y creo que hay algunos más. Estos se basan en rearmar el jar juntando las clases de las diferentes dependencias y mergeando los manifest. Por otro lado está Spring Boot que también arma un jar ejecutable con dependencias dentro pero almacenando los jar dependientes en lugar de sus clases y usando un class loader que le permite buscar dentro de esos jars (esto java no lo soporta de forma nativa).

Comment: Sí, eso es lo más habitual. De hecho he tenido que ponerme a revisar la documentación porque en los más de 13 años que llevo con Java, nunca he creado un jar sin dependencias incluídas y estoy acostumbrado a usar Spring y un IDE para automatizar todo.